# Get all magento attributes via api with code and type

Tags: magento, attributes

I like to get all magento attributes (for products and attributes) with its attribute_code and attribute_type.

I wrote this code:

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection(); 
foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
   echo $attribute->getAttributeCode() . ":" . $attribute->getAttributeType() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I get output like this:

tax_class_id:
gift_message_available:
price_type:
sku_type:
weight_type:
price_view:

I will get the code but not the type.

What could be the problem? How do I need to fix the code.

Comment: Hi,

Could you tell please what do you mean speaking about "attribute_type". Do you mean "entity_type_id" or "backend_type" or may be something else? Because attributes has no "attribute_type" field in magento.

Comment: With attribute_type, i if a attribute is a dropdown, multi dropdown, textfield and so in

Answer (score 1):

As MagestyApps.com wrote, the *attribute_type* does not exists in Magento.

It depends of what data you want :

- The data type (int, varchar, datetime, static, etc.)

  $attribute->getBackendType()
- The class that manage the attribute

  $attribute->getBackendModel()
- The kind of input it uses (input, select, radio, etc.)

  $attribute->getFrontendInput()